# Ruby Hashes vs. Arrays: quickest way to find an item?

Tags: ruby

I'm loading large TXT files into an array or hash using ruby. The input file contains more than 1'000'000 MD5 hash values, alphabetically sorted, no duplicates.

What is the fastest way in Ruby, to find out if a certain hash value is present in my array or hash? Currently I use an array and "include?".

```
def loadhashlist
@all_hash_values = Array.new
    f = File.readlines("inputmd5.txt").each do |row|
    @all_hash_values.push(row.gsub("\n",""))
    end
end

loadhashlist

def hashlookup(file)
md5 = file.getMd5
    if @all_hash_values.include? md5
    #code goes here
    end
end
```

Comment: Additionally to the answer you can clean up the load using `@all_hash_values = File.foreach("inputmd5.txt").map {|row| row.chomp }`. `File#foreach` returns an `Enumerator` then `Enumerator#map` will return a new `Array` based on the return values in the block and `String#chomp` will remove the trailing new line character. Right now you are creating an `Array` using `File#readlines` just to place the values into another `Array` (`@all_hash_values`) which will have performance impacts as well.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for helping me out on that one! huge difference! Loading a inputmd5.txt with 10'000'000 lines, used to take around 40 seconds. Using your code, I'm done in 9 sec!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could use an array, which would be `O(logN)` at best, but it is both faster and semantically better to use a set.

```
require 'set'

hashes = Set.new
hashes << 'foo'
hashes << 'bar'
hashes.include?('bar') # => true
```

In ruby sets are implemented with hashtables, so lookups are `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks Sergio. In the first step where I load thousands of hashvalues in either a set or an array, they are pretty much the same speed. Overall it's very fast: I load 10'000'000 MD5 hashvalues into a set/array in 10seconds! Using a set during the lookup part of the script, where I ask IF a certain hashvalue is in the set, has proven to be a bit faster then using an array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Array#include?` is O(N).

Instead, since the array is already sorted, you could use [`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-bsearch), which is O(lgN).

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check for the implementation details in ruby (and if you absolutely rely upon it you would have to benchmark) but from what I learned in my CS classes this should boil down to:

- Array: O(n) or O(log n) based on method used
- Hash (assuming the md5 is the key): O(1)

So I'd go with the Hash.

Comment: `O(1)` for hashes is obviously for _search by key_, not by value.

Comment: I at least meant to have written that it would require the md5 to serve as the key.

Comment: And what would you suggest to serve as a value? If nothing, it would be `Set` as [correctly] suggested by Sergio in the top answer.

Comment: You are right and that is why I upvoted his solution. At the time of writing the solution wasn't yet proposed and I wasn't aware of `Set` (keep on forgetting them). Just wanted to clarify my intend to not confuse later readers.